# Rails rake rollbar:test didn't pass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, monitoring, rollbar

I was trying to use rollbar gem to monitor error message.
I followed its [document](https://rollbar.com/docs/notifier/rollbar-gem/#rails).

Add `gem 'rollbar'`, and `rails generate rollbar POST_SERVER_ITEM_ACCESS_TOKEN`.

(I did changed the `POST_SERVER_ITEM_ACCESS_TOKEN` to my key)

But after I run `rake rollbar:test`, it only threw `Test error from rollbar:test` in dashboard.
[image]

### Update

**initializers/rollbar**

```
Rollbar.configure do |config|
 if Rails.env.test?
    config.enabled = false
 end
```

In console

```
rake rollbar:test                                                                                                                           16:21:14
Testing manual report...
[Rollbar] Scheduling item
[Rollbar] Sending item
[Rollbar] Success
[Rollbar] Details: https://rollbar.com/instance/uuid?uuid=1f4c4e35-df5f-4606-916d-d97341b01dc7 (only available if report was successful)
Setting up the controller.
Processing...
Started GET "/verify" for  at 2016-12-02 16:21:21 +0800
```

Comment: Did you restart your server?

Comment: Yes, I restart my server.

Comment: what did you expect it to do? That looks completely normal to me - it raised a test error as you asked it to.

Comment: Oh, I thought it will display it's fine....I will add anther exception to test

Comment: Thanks, the error is right.

Answer (score 0):

Check your rollbar config, probably it's disabled in development mode. 
https://github.com/rollbar/rollbar-gem/blob/master/lib/generators/rollbar/templates/initializer.rb#L7

Comment: I check, it seems no problem, and I update my question

Comment: Have you tried manually generate any exception to see it in Rollbar dashboard?

Comment: No, I thought it will show something like everything is right .